# Converting letters to a valued number

Tags: python

Hi im new to python and im new to stack forum but I hope to find some luck here.

I have a text file containing letters a-z in a list that I am importing.

a

b

c

..

..

And I want to make the numbers have a number value so when it prints it says something like

a = 1

b = 2

c = 3
..

..

How can I make this work?

This is what I have come to, but this will only print the txt file.

```
f = open('alpha.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
print (file_contents)
f.close()
```

Comment: Can you let us know if you want each character to be numbered based on where they are in the alphabet or if you just want them numbered by where they appear in the list? My solution is very different from the others, so i think it'd be nice to know what we are trying to solve exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('alpha.txt') as f:
    lines = list(enumerate((line for line in (l.strip() for l in f) if line),start = 1)) # also skip empty lines
    for item in lines:
        print ("{}={}".format(item[1],item[0]))
```

output:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

or:

```
with open('alpha.txt') as f:
    for line in enumerate(f,start = 1):
        print("{}={}".format(line[1][0], line[0]))
```

output:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

or

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
   for idx, line in enumerate(f,start = 1):
       print('{}={}'.format(line[0], idx))
```

output:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
with open('alpha.txt', 'r') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        print('{letter} = {number}'.format(letter=line, number=idx + 1)
```

Some notes:

- The [`with`](https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) statement makes it so that no matter what happens, you don't need to worry about closing the file, because it will be closed automatically at the end of the block.
- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives you an index (starting at 0) for each item of the iterable (in this case, each line of the file).
- I'm using a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to format the output in a readable way.

Comment: print('{letter} = {number}'.format(letter=line, number=idx + 1) **letter=line, gives me an error where name line is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `string` lib:

```
[print(c, '=', i+1) for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)]
```

Output:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the letters into their numerical value by calling `ord()` on a character.

`ord('a')` will be equal to 97. if you want to offset your characters to start at 1 you can either subtract 96, or you can use something like `offset = ord('a')-1` to be a little more dynamic about it.

```
import string # dont need to import for your version
letters = string.ascii_letters[:26] # lowercase letters for testing

offset = ord('a') - 1
for letter in letters:
```

outputs:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
```

etc.

edit: my solution is different from the other ones in that I'm actually translating each letter into its values. If you only want to number the solutions as they come out, then my solution would be wrong.

For example if given

```
letters =  ['b', 'c', 'a']
```

my solution will output

```
b  =  2
c  =  3
a  =  1
```

where as the other posted solutions will still number the letters

```
b = 1
c = 2
a = 3
```